# Type casting a custom c++ class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If I have my own SString class in c++ and I want to be able to do this:

```
SString x("text");
LPCSTR p = (LPCSTR)x;
cout<<p;
```

How do I do it?

Comment: side note: better use `static_cast<LPCTSTR>(x);` always prefer c++ style casts over c style casts; they're easier to spot, and they're more restricted in what they can do, so there's less chance of errors creeping in by casting!

Comment: You could overload `std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream&, const SString&)` instead

Comment: thank you, but I am also very interested in the casting part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `conversion operator to LPCSTR` in your class `SString`. If you can use `C++11` this operator should be `explicit`.

```
operator LPCSTR() const { /*return data*/ };
```

Also you can create some function like (i think this variant is better, than conversion operator)

```
LPCSTR asLPCSTR() const { /*return data*/ };
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what ForEveR said, note that you can also overload

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& str, const SString& ss);
```

and call

```
cout<<x;
```

directly.